# Histories in Scott-Potter set theory

Tags: set-theory, foundations, philosophy

I have been reading Michael Potter's *Set Theory and its Philosophy*. I am confused by the concept of a *history*, which I understand is somewhat unconventional. The definition given is as follows:

> The **accumulation** of a, $\mathop{\mathrm{acc}}(a)$, is the set {$x | x \text{ is an urelement or } \exists b \in a (x \in b \text{ or } x \subset b)$}.

> If $ \forall v \in V: v = \mathop{\mathrm{acc}}(V\cap v))$ then $V$ is a **history**.

More information can be found on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scott%E2%80%93Potter_set_theory

In particular it would seem that not all sets may be elements of a history, as each element of a history must be equal to an accumulation and thus contain all urelements.

I thought I had some understanding of the iterative conception of sets, which in my mind is linked to some variation on Von Neumann's hierarchy. I am having a hard time linking this to Potter's set theory.

Thank you for any insights or pointers!

Comment: Some comments into Potter, [Iterative Set Theory (1993)](https://academic.oup.com/pq/article-abstract/43/171/178/1570690?redirectedFrom=fulltext)

Comment: We may imagine a "temporal" process with stages one after the other, similar to the Von Neumann universe. The *history* is the collection of all stages earlier than a specified one; the *accumulation* of a history is the set collecting all urelements plus all the elements and subsets of the stages in the history. The "convoluted" definitions above are manufactured in order to avoid the notion of "stages", using only urelement, element and subset.

Comment: Both histories and accumulations are collections of sets with **all** urelements (individuals): an history is closed with respect to the "accumulation process" of all its sets.